# How to filter different url in order work with same servlets?

Tags: servlets, url-rewriting, servlet-filters

Assume I have some servlets called /servlet1, /servlet2, etc in my code.

My goal is to serve two different applications with the same set of servlets:

/myapp1/servlet1 -> use /login with a parameter called myapp1

/myapp2/servlet2 -> use /login with a parameter called myapp2

I guess I have to use filter and filter mapping but I had no luck make it work so far.

Answer (score 0):

here is an exemple of filter:

public class LoginFilter implements Filter {

```
public LoginFilter() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}


public void destroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

public String clean(String s){
    s=s.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9]", "");
    s=s.trim();
    return s;
}

public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    HttpServletRequest req=(HttpServletRequest) request;
    HttpServletResponse resp=(HttpServletResponse) response;

    String user=req.getParameter("username");
    String pass=req.getParameter("password");
    req.removeAttribute("username");
    req.removeAttribute("password");

    user=clean(user);
    pass=clean(pass);

    req.setAttribute("username", user);
    req.setAttribute("password", pass);

    chain.doFilter(req, response);
}


public void init(FilterConfig fConfig) throws ServletException {

}
```

}

and here is web.xml

```
 <filter>
<filter-name>LoginFilter</filter-name>
<filter-class>pack.LoginFilter</filter-class>  </filter>
```

`<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>LoginFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/some-url-patter</url-pattern> </filter-mapping>`

you have to have the same url pattern as the servlets too add the filter. you can have any number of filters.
it works something like this : filter1->filter2->filter3->...->servlet